# If directory meets a condition, then do wc in each

Tags: bash, shell, loops, if-statement

I have to write a script where if a condition is met, (example: the folder starts with 'A') then recursively open each dir that meets the condition and do `wc` on the files inside. If there are more than 50 files inside the dir, echo the dir name with `wc`.

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried.

Comment: This is a fairly simple task and you can do it if you try, when you get stuck somewhere then ask your doubt.

Comment: <code>

CONDITION='ls | grep A'

if [ $CONDITION ];then

 for FILE in $CONDITION  
 do
  ls -l | wc -l
  echo "$FILE"
 done
 
fi
</code>

Comment: @BlazejEs http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to find all the directories starting with A that contain more than 50 files.

The following command lists all the directories meeting a string name condition if they have more than 50 files in them

```
NAME="A*"
find . -type d -name "$NAME" -exec sh -c 'echo $(ls "{}" |wc -l) "{}"' \; | awk 'int($1)>=50'
```

Answer (score 0):

This script should wrk for you:

```
PREFIX="A"

while read dir; do
   numDir=$(d=( $dir*/ .$dir/*/ ) && echo "${#d[@]}")
   numFileDir=$(a=( $dir/* $dir/.* ) && echo "${#a[@]}")
   [[ ((numFileDir-numDir > 50)) ]] && echo "$dir: " $((numFileDir-numDir))
done < <(find . -type d -name "$PREFIX")
```